# How to disable/enable tabs in Actionbar Sherlock

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I added several tabs in my app:

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );
ActionBar.Tab destTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
destTab.setText( R.string.blah ).setIcon( android.R.drawable.ic_blah ).setTabListener( this );
getSupportActionBar().addTab( destTab );
```

They work like charm.

Now I want to disable them, so that they do not react on taps. And eventually re-enable them later.

Any fast solutions?
TIA

Comment: Disable them? Will hiding them do the trick? Or do they have to visible, but just not react when they are clicked?

Comment: The scenario is like this: the user hits the "GO!" button, which renders the whole layout but the "cancel" button inactive. So yes, everything on the screen including the tabs should remain visible.

Comment: That's not possible with the exposed API for the ActionBar Tabs.